# Generate BPMN using Java Library

Tags: java, bpmn, business-process-management, kie

Trying to generate a BPMN diagram, even a basic one with start event, end event and some user tasks. Is there any Java libraries or API's available that would help me achieve this.
Have searched around a lot but could not find any suitable.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a Java lib, you can use the [Camunda model builder API](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/model-api/bpmn-model-api/).

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        BpmnModelInstance modelInst;
        try {
        // File file = new File(ModelModifier.class.getClassLoader().getResource("process1.bpmn").toURI());
            File file = new File("./src/main/resources/process1.bpmn");
        //  modelInst = Bpmn.readModelFromFile(file);
            modelInst = Bpmn.createProcess()
                    .name("Twitter QA")
                    .executable()
                    .startEvent()
                    .userTask().id("ApproveTweet").name("Approve Tweet")
                    .exclusiveGateway().id("isApproved").name("Approved?")
                    .condition("approved", "#{approved}")
                    .serviceTask().id("sendTweet").name("Send tweet")
                    .endEvent().name("Tweet sent")
                    .moveToLastGateway()
                    // done();
                    // Gateway gateway = modelInst.getModelElementById("isApproved");
                    // gateway.builder()
                    .condition("Not approved", "#{!approved}")
                    .serviceTask().name("Send Rejection")
                    .endEvent().name("Tweet rejected").done();

            log.info("Flow Elements - Name : Id : Type Name");
            modelInst.getModelElementsByType(UserTask.class).forEach(e -> log.info("{} : {} : {}", e.getName(), e.getId(), e.getElementType().getTypeName()));

            Bpmn.writeModelToFile(file, modelInst);
//        file.createNewFile("/tmp/testDiagram2.bpmn")

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is a project with a few examples: https://github.com/rob2universe/bpmn-creator.

If you are also comfortable with js then [bpmn.js](https://bpmn.io/toolkit/bpmn-js/) from bpmn.io would be preferable

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you would want something with a UI that renders said BPMN diagram, and likely allows it to be created by the user.  BPMN.io offers [BPMN.js](https://bpmn.io/toolkit/bpmn-js/) ([git hub link](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js)).  You can use their modeler online to see how it works.  I've not looked at the licensing to integrate it into a solution, so not sure if it is a good fit for your use case.

I'd also look at some of the open source packages.  [Camunda](https://camunda.com) used to have an open source community edition, which I assume had modeling capabilities, but I've not checked in on the current state of that in a few years.

Comment: I wanted a dependency which provides methods and API's that i can use in my code to generate a bpmn file

Comment: Maybe more context would help for suggesting an answer.  What is the source of the details that would go into the BPMN file?  The code I linked will generate a BPMN diagram from the out put it generates. It is just JS code, so you could create the input it is expecting and have it output the diagram.  In the end BPMN is just XML so the hard part is mapping whatever you have to a BPMN compliant format.